# Column alias in order by

Tags: sql, oracle

I got this:

```
select ..., sum(value) as Total_Value
from ...
order by Total_Value
```

Long story short, why is the ORDER BY working in here?
Aren't column alias supposed to work only on an upper Select levels like a select inside a select?
Why is it working inside the same select?

PS: Using Oracle 11, I was told that column alias on "Order by" could give problems on migration, how far is that true?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Maybe this helps you a little - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.6-en/problems-with-alias.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY` is called after previous query is finished. `Order BY` receive a table as an input. So if

```
select ..., sum(value) as Total_Value
from ...
```

works then

```
select ..., sum(value) as Total_Value
from ...
order by Total_Value
```

will also work.

Comment: Will there be any problem with migrating this column alias in order by to another database manager ?

Comment: That is pretty standard, I think. Most databases will not allow you to use it in a where clause though.

Comment: It seems, it works with Oracle, MySQL and MSSQL - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81cd5/1. How you moved from `order by` to `where`, it's different question...